TypeScript loses type constraint on keyof through multiple levels of generic types
I have a problem that when I introduce multiple levels of generic types, TypeScript type inference "forgets" the key type constraint:
type InnerMap = Record<string, unknown>;
type OuterMap<T extends InnerMap = InnerMap> = {
    inner: T;
};

class Example<TMap extends OuterMap = OuterMap> {
    method<K extends keyof TMap['inner']>(key: K) {
        const a: string = key; // Error: Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    }
}

Playground
In the example, it's obvious that the K generic type can only be a string (it's a key of the InnerMap which is a Record<string, unknown> but for some reason, TS "loosens" the type constraint from string to string | number | symbol.
One "fix" i found is telling TS that the generic type can only be a string, but this is a bit hacky:
method<K extends keyof TMap['inner'] & string>(key: K) {

What is this problem called and is there a better way to fix it?

Your problem can indeed be "fixed" by explicitly narrowing the key type. This isn't hacky; it's how TypeScript ensures type safety given its design constraints. By adding & string to K extends keyof TMap['inner'], you explicitly narrow down the key type to string, which aligns with the InnerMap definition.
A suggestion for a title would be: TypeScript: Constraining Generic Key Types to Strings in Multi-Level Generic Types.

T extends Record<string, unknown> does not mean that keyof T extends string. You can always add properties when extending, T might well have a symbol or numeric key, as shown in this playground link. Does that address why you have to use & string if you need such a restriction? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

It is not "hacky"; inside the generic function, TypeScript can't know for sure that the key will be a string. TypeScript might be able to infer the types correctly when you pass the generic values because they provide more information but this information is not available within the generic function/class declaration.
This is very common, you should worry a lot about ensuring that the function arguments and return type are correctly inferred.
There will be cases like this where an additional annotation will be required. As long as the annotation is not any, I would not worry too much about it.
